# Irregular grid with expanded items

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-grid

I have a grid where each odd row contains a different number of items that the even rows. Something like 4/3/4/3 and so on...

I've managed to do it with the next code:

```
  .grid-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 0;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 40px;
}

.grid-item {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(7n), .grid-item:nth-child(7n-1), .grid-item:nth-child(7n-2) {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
```

This works fine and created the irregular grid, but my problem starts when I try to go further:
I added a field in the backend panel where you are able to select if a grid item expands and takes the space of two items:

```
.grid-item.expanded {
      grid-column: span 6;
}
```

For sure the grid gets messed since I'm generating this composition by calling the items by its 'nth-child'; so when an item gets expanded, the CSS keeps using the same criteria and the grid gets altered.

Is there any way to accomplish this?
Would be great to generate the layout by targeting each row and not using 'nth-child' numeration.

I hope it's clear enough.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using flexbox.

```css
body * {
  border: 1px solid;
}

[ctr] {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

[ctr]>div {
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 4);
  height: 100px;
}

[ctr]>div:nth-last-child(7n),
[ctr]>div:nth-last-child(7n-1),
[ctr]>div:nth-last-child(7n-2) {
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 3);
}


/* Expanded */

[ctr]>div:nth-child(6) {
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 1.5);
}

[ctr]>div:nth-child(9) {
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 1.5);
}
```

```html
<div ctr>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I'm afraid I have the same problem. I don't specifically tell where those expanded items are appearing, the client will using the panel. So calling the items by nth-child keeps being the problem.

Comment: @Anta Hum...I don't really understand what you mean by that so i can't suggest anything, The problem was the grid being distorted after expanding one cell that's why my answer is for. If you can explain further what you mean.

Comment: I basically create this irregular grid by calling the elements with 'nth-child' (like you also did). When I also expand one column, this criteria gets messed since the numeration for the 'nth-child' doesn't make sense anymore – i.e one expanded column takes the space of two normal ones, so if you expand 7n-2, the 7n should not use 100% / 3 anymore.